# lambda calculus triple in Python NLP

Tags: python, nlp, lambda-calculus

I have a list of properties and i need to make a logical representation of a sentence using lambda calculus for example   for the property 'located in'   it needs to return `(x,y) | < x, located in ,y >`

i tried this but it's not correct  :

```
for index, row in properties.iterrows():
    def parse_r(properties,x,y):
        return lambda x, y: <x, row['Property'], y>
```

i get this error

> return lambda x, y: 
>                           ^
>      SyntaxError: invalid syntax

the system should understand that the relation between x and y is what's in the middle and get the needed logical representation 
how can i do this with lambda calculus in python code ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
for index, row in properties.iterrows():
    def parse_r(properties,x,y):
        return lambda x, y: '<{}, {}, {}>'.format(x, row['Property'], y)
```

Comment: thank you for your response. May i ask you about quantifiers in Lambda calculus  for example i have  "who is the inventor of facebook "this should be  ∃x <facebook,inventor,x>   how can i achieve such a representation with python and lambda-calculus ?